# To Be Filled By O.E.M. We are the 'OEM' and we don't know how to do it. Any hint?

Tags: hardware, oem

- We send appliances to customers, and since some days ago the machines come from a new vendor.
- The machines have new BIOS and motherboards: http://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios
- We would like to use /sys/class/dmi/id to identify the machines, so they become unique by its serial number.
- This is the output that we can get from id directory:

  ```
  id # for filename in *; do [[ -f ${filename} ]] && echo ${filename}: && cat ${filename}; done  

  bios_date:  07/12/2010  
  bios_vendor: American Megatrends Inc.  
  bios_version:  080015  
  board_asset_tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
  board_name: To be filled by O.E.M.
  board_serial: To be filled by O.E.M.
  board_vendor: To be filled by O.E.M.
  board_version: To be filled by O.E.M.
  ...
  ```
- We have tried some tools to edit these BIOS values without success.

Has anyone edited DMI data before? Please teach me. :)

Comment: You should be asking your supplier, not us.

Comment: Thanks Robert, easier to read.    John, we are to small for them, they just sell, anyway we will try your approach once again.

Comment: if you're large enough to buy from them you are large enough to ask them to support the product you are buying.

Comment: The OEM is the _Original Equipment Manufacturer_. If you buy the machines from someone else, then the someone else is the OEM, not you. You need the OEM to configure that.

Comment: The OEM in this case is the motherboard manufacturer, not you.

Answer (score 4):

If you are the OEM then you should have an account with your BIOS provider, and your BIOS provider should be supplying you with a utility to customize the BIOS.

Comment: We are the OEM was just a mater of speeak. We are a small company buying stuff directly to the manufacturer. we are not the OEM, otherwise the question would be just silly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some of regular bios editors, like Award bios editor, AMI bios editor.

Some of them will let you edit basic fields or depends on how updated bios editor is...

I've seen cases where manufacturer gives utilities to edit basic fields in the BIOS, it's worth of trying and asking such utility (post logo, your own serial number or so).

Comment: Not since 2011. :)